UnauthorizedAccessException mientras se ejecuta como admin
estoy ejectutando mi app con permisos de admin (salió en el UAC) y me salió esto: . La excepción es System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\rayel\AppData\Local\Temp\denetemp\TempMetaZip' is denied., no lo entiendo porqué me salió esto si la estoy ejecutando como admin, y además estoy hablando de appdata, no de c:\windows, así que debería ir

No sé por qué podría ser. Por ejemplo, a mí me pasa que luego de crear un proyecto de NodeJS, no puedo borrar la carpeta manualmente ni con permisos de administrador. La única forma que encontré es usando npm prune primero. Volviendo a tu pregunta, esa ruta existe? Podrías compartir el archivo .zip a ver si tenemos el mismo problema? Y no olvides agregar tu código

sí, existe, de hecho, la compruebo, con Ejecutar (Win+R) pongo esa ruta y se abre, solo que está vacía por eso.
La linea que falla según el debugger es:
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(tempdir + "TempMetaZip", metazip);
Esa línea no se llega a ejecutar ya que nunca he podido ver los archivos extraídos.

El botón de detalles no aporta información útil al problema?
